# Cannot reference dll file in project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-store-apps

This is my first time trying to use a `dll` file in visual studio (2012) so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am trying to get `sqlite` into my project following this [tutorial](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/using-sqlite-in-your-windows-8-metro-style-applications/)

I right click on the project in the `Solution Explorer` and click `Add References`

I then click on the browse tab and find where I have the dll file,click ok then ok in visual studio and I get an error saying `Reference to *dll path* could not be added. Please make sure the file is accessible and that is it a valid assembly or COM component.`

did I miss a step here or something?

The file is located in my dropbox folder (where my whole project is) and the project is a windows store application is that matters

Comment: Have you tried opening visual studio as administrator?  What are the permissions on the drop box folder?

Comment: Did you try copying the file locally to see if you can access the file and add ref to the local copy?

Comment: @Jason local copy does the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a direct answer but instead of referencing the dll directly, you should install the [Visual Studio extension for SQLite](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23f6c55a-4909-4b1f-80b1-25792b11639e?SRC=VSIDE). The extension includes the dlls for all platforms (x86, x64, ARM). It also makes sure that the right dll is used for the platform that you are building for.

After you install the extension, it will appear in the references dialog under Windows -> Extensions. Also, when you use the extension, you must change all your project build configurations to be x86 or x64 (on the desktop) or Arm (for Arm devices). It will fail to build if you use AnyCPU.